# HttpWebRequest link api

Tags: .net, httpwebrequest

I create this for check IP Address in Fraud system.

```
        private void checkFrodSystem()
    {
        try
        {
            HttpWebRequest WebReq = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("check.getipintel.net/check.php?ip=" + ip + "&contact=12323r3g34g3234246@test.com");
            HttpWebResponse WebResp = (HttpWebResponse)WebReq.GetResponse();
            Stream answer = WebResp.GetResponseStream();
            StreamReader subanswer = new StreamReader(answer);
            count = (Convert.ToDouble(subanswer.ReadToEnd())) + 0.1;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            textBoxOut.Clear();
        }
    }
```

But I catch Exception: 400 "Bad Request", Why??!

Comment: Your URI witch you passed in method Create should include one of the following prefix http:// https://  ftp:// and file://

Comment: I try http:// and get exception again(